# Geometric Motivation for Inner Product

Tags: geometry, inner-products, motivation, gram-schmidt

I think some background will make the kind of answer I'm looking for clearer. I'm trying to think of an elementary proof of the Pythagorean Theorem. I don't like the geometric proofs because they all seem to rely on some kind of trick or clever construction. In particular, they don't seem to shed any light on why we look at the square root of the sum of squares to find a distance.

By contrast, the inner product seems like an elementary way to prove the Pythagorean theorem that does give us some understanding of why we should square and take square roots. Briefly: you use Gram-Schmidt to convert a basis to an orthonormal basis. Taking the inner product of a vector with itself in the orthonormal basis immediately gives you the Pythagorean theorem.

This seems like a promising approach since the defining properties of an inner product (linearity, symmetry, and positive definitenes) are pretty basic. But, even though they're basic, I'm not sure how to motivate them geometrically. So, at the level of geometry, why should we want to consider an object like an inner product on a vector space? Of course, we know by Cauchy-Schwarz that the inner product helps us define magnitude and angle, but I don't think that's obvious from its defining properties.

Perhaps the thing to do is to start with the relationship $\langle v, w \rangle = ||v || ||w|| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $w$ and $v$, and then argue that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ has the properties of an inner product.

Comment: If you use dot product tp find distances, at some point you will use Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: I don't think relying on "trick" are in any sense bad at all.

Comment: @DavidCheng Not generally no. I usually like tricky proofs, especially if they're short. But for fundamental results, I think there should be a naive way to see that they're true. The Pythagorean Theorem is so basic that I feel like there should be a way to prove it by just pushing definitions of easily motivated objects.

Comment: To put a finer point on it, I don't like the geometric proofs because they don't seem to tell you why the Pythagorean Theorem is true. By contrast, the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus makes basic estimates based on basic, obvious facts about the integral. A proof of the inverse function that I like sets up a contraction mapping, which assures you that the inverse is something you can calculate and helps you understand why we need a non-zero jacobian.

Comment: One of the core problems that occurs to me when trying to move the proof of the Pythagorean property into a normed or inner product space is: how do you know that such a space reflects Euclidean geometry? For example, there are norms like the Manhattan metric which are perfectly good norms, but disagree with the Euclidean notion of what distance is. Proofs of the Pythagorean theorem come down at some point to planar geometry (perpendicular/parallel lines, finding equal angles in configurations of lines, etc), so somehow you need to argue that an inner product space reflects Euclidean space.

Comment: @Joppy That's helpful, thank you. Yes, the crux of the issue is showing that inner product spaces have the structure of euclidean geometry. As mathematicians, we know this to be true. Linear transformations which preserve the inner product (plus translations) are precisely the symmetries of euclidean geometry. But how to make it clear that we should start from the inner product?